# Search Exercise error "Unknown column in where clause"

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been coding a search exercise when I stumbled upon this error

> Unknown column in where clause

As I type a number to search for the cottage number, it returns without fail, but if I type a customer name the error shows.

This is my SQL query:

```
         $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pastrec
        WHERE (`cott_num` LIKE $query) OR (`cus_name` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());
```

I know that I have a problem in my query but I'm not sure what.

**UPDATE**

I've omitted the `cott_num` as search parameter and it worked! You can search names but you can't search numbers. I've reversed the technique above and omitted the `cus_name` and it also works! you can search cottage numbers but you can't search names.

I really want to have a search that search both cottage number or customer name.

Comment: Show us the column names of the `pastrec` table.

Comment: cott_num is integer in your table?

Comment: cott_num is an integer and cus_name is varchar

Comment: Note that the above code, and the answer from Awlad Liton below, are potentially susceptible to SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to compare number or string in this query. When you are comparing number (id) you should use equal. you need to use quotation because if you input a string then it will trying to comapre like this: `cott_num = your_string`    this is cause error in mysql.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pastrec
                WHERE (`cott_num` = '$query') OR (`cus_name` LIKE '%".$query."%')";
echo $sql;

  $raw_results = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: cott_num exists in my table as an Integer. If I search using cott_num as a parameter it can search data which has a cottage number of (e.g) 5 but If I use text as parameter (cus_name) it doesnt show anything and only result to the error above.

P.S. Ive tried the top code but it returns the same error

Comment: @user3036014: can you try my first code? run the echoed query in your mysql server. and see what you have got.

Comment: I typed 5 as a search parameter and this echoed
SELECT * FROM pastrec WHERE (`cott_num` = 5) OR (`cus_name` LIKE '%5%')

I've tried string as a parameter and this echoed
SELECT * FROM pastrec WHERE (`cott_num` = renz) OR (`cus_name` LIKE '%renz%')

Comment: did you run above query in your sql server?

Comment: yes and it returned just that.

BTW, the first query when I used a number. It displayed the data.
but on the second query, that where clause error is displayed

Comment: @user3036014: i have updated my answer try this. It should work now

Comment: Thank you kind sir! It does work now. Care to explain the code?